# How can i arrange an array to make a constant loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want the loop to find and use the right code that i have written for over than 1000 datas directly without trying them one by one. The purpose of this coding should be to apply a green background to the right data-id that the loop finallt found.

```js
var answerKey = [{
    q: "58b988ff62279282090dd314"
  }, {
    q: "58b988ff62279282090dc152"
  }, {
    q: "58b988ff62279282090dbf09"
  }

  // etc.
];

var questionTxt = $(this).find('data-id');

questionTxt.each(function() {
  $(this).css("background", "lime");
  return false; // End loop
});

function getAnswer(questionText) {
  for (var J = answerKey.length - 1; J >= 0; --J) {
    var zRegExp = new RegExp(answerKey[J].q, 'i');
    if (zRegExp.test(questionText))
      return answerKey[J].q;
  }
  return null;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="question-text" class="question sp-element border-radius active">Which one is the biggest country in the world ?</div>
<ul class="answers" id="answers">
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc14f" class="answer sp-element border-radius active">Germany</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc150" class="answer sp-element border-radius active">Swiss</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc152" class="answer sp-element border-radius active">China</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc151" class="answer sp-element border-radius active">Belgium</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47804943/how-can-i-add-background-color-by-data-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query for an element where the `data-id` matches one of the id's in your input data.

```js
const input = [
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dd314"}, 
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dc152"},
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dbf09"}
];

input.forEach(({q}) => $(`[data-id="${q}"]`).css("background", "lime"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Which one is the biggest country in the world ?</div>
<ul>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc14f">Germany</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc150">Swiss</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc152">China</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc151">Belgium</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could achieve the same result without jQuery, like this:

```js
const input = [
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dd314"}, 
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dc152"},
  {q: "58b988ff62279282090dbf09"}
];

input.forEach(({q}) => {
  const res = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${q}"]`);
  if(res) {
    res.style.background = 'lime';
  }
});
```

```html
<div>Which one is the biggest country in the world ?</div>
<ul>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc14f">Germany</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc150">Swiss</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc152">China</li>
  <li data-id="58b988ff62279282090dc151">Belgium</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i couldnt make this work on greasemonkey. i added it to the jquery 2.1.1 library but it wont work :/

Comment: Im sorry it was my mistake your coding works perfectly fine

Comment: @NurBar in case you run into any further problems I've added a version that doesn't use jQuery. Also, please accept my answer if you felt like it provided you with a solution to your problem (by pressing the green check mark next to the question).

Comment: How can use regular expression on q value ? Please lasttime help me :) its changing some value so i need use in this way {q: "5...................bf09"} thanks olian

Comment: @NurBar take a loot at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/I30PNZ/3) and see if you can make sense of it :)

Comment: @NurBar There is a button on the left hand side (on that page) that says `code generator`. You will have to try a bit on your own before asking question :) good luck